# How to print \n as a text without creating newline within a quote in R cat

Tags: r, linux, shell, sed

I want to print the following lines in a text file  using cat function in R:

```
shebang line
for file in *.out; do sed $'s/Cluster/\\\n&/g' $file > "$(basename "$file" .out)_split.out2"; done
```

To do this I use:

```
cat("shebang line","for file in *.out; do sed $'s/Cluster/\\\n&/g' $file > \"$(basename \"$file\" .out)_split.out2\"; done",file="output.txt",sep="\n",append=TRUE)
```

But in output.txt, I get:

```
shebang line
for file in *.out; do sed $'s/Cluster/\
&/g' $file > "$(basename "$file" .out)_split.out2"; done
```

Seems like it creates a extra newline and don't print \n within single quote.
Considering that I do need to use \n as a separator, how can I print the character as is without creating a newline?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

`cat("shebang line","for file in *.out; do sed $'s/Cluster/\\\\\\n&/g' $file > \"$(basename \"$file\" .out)_split.out2\"; done",file="output.txt",sep="\n",append=TRUE)`

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.